# How to configure exe setup with database on another pc...?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I created my first winform application using c# windows form application in visual studio 2015. It contains some database operations such as insertion, deletion, and updates. The database is created in SQL-Server. Then I compiled the solution and it worked fine on my computer. When I try to run the application on another computer, it is throwing an SQL-Server connection error. Can you please help out, I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

When You run the `EXE` file on some other computer you should make sure that that computer is able to connect to your database server, So you should either Add the computer to your network and provide necessary rights to connect, or Host the database on Some Network Location from where everyone can access it.

Another Idea is if you want to keep the Database as Local for each Computer, try using the  Dynamic Configuration using the `App.Config` File.Save and retrieve the Database Connection String from the App.Config File and when you copy the EXE to some other machine, Copy this file along with that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here seems to be on the client side. The user on the client/machine that runs the application on, doesn't seem to have the rights to connect to the server or database. You need to grant the needed rights to each user that will use the client.
However this concept allows the users to also directly connect to the database and run CRUD operations if they know how and are allowed to.

A more common way is to use a dedicated service user/account and include the credentials to the connection string in your application. [Here are the basics](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

If you need to make sure users don't read the credentials from the config file, use [encrypted configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh8x3tas.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to permanently attach a database file (.mdf), which can be done by following steps: from the Data Connections node

> ```
> Open the shortcut menu for Data Connections and choose Add New Connection.
>
> The Add Connection dialog box appears.
>
> Choose the Change button.
>
> The Change Data Source dialog box appears.
>
> Select Microsoft SQL Server and choose the OK button.
>
> The Add Connection dialog box reappears, with Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient) displayed in the Data source text box.
>
> In the Server Name box, type or browse to the path to the local instance of SQL Server. You can type the following:
>
>     "." for the default instance on your computer.
>
>     "(LocalDB)\v11.0" for the default instance of SQL Server Express LocalDB.
>
>     ".\SQLEXPRESS" for the default instance of SQL Server Express.
>
> For information about SQL Server Express LocalDB and SQL Server Express, see Local Data Overview.
>
> Select either Use Windows Authentication or Use SQL Server Authentication.
>
> Choose Attach a database file, Browse, and open an existing .mdf file.
>
> Choose the OK button.
>
> The new database appears in Server Explorer. It will remain connected to SQL Server until you explicitly detach it.
> ```